# when I want to rewrite url with htaccess like localhost/sample/12 htaccess is looking for sample and 12 directory names

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to use .htaccess to rewrite url.

I want this url localhost/sample.php?x=12 rewrite to localhost/sample/12

I used this code

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule sample/([0-9]+)/?$ sample.php?x=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

but when i enter the url localhost/sample/12 web server looking for a directory named sample and a subfolder 12 in it.

what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your rewrite rule to below and it will work.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)x=12($|&)
RewriteRule ^sample\.php$ /sample/12?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```